# JavaScript note edit function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm making a note-taking app and would like to be able to edit a note and then update it in the database. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="note">This is a note.</div>

<a href=\"#\" class='note_edit note_functions' id='texteditbutton' onclick='note_edit()'>Edit Note</a>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
function note_edit(){

    var textbox = document.createElement("textarea");

    var adjust = document.getElementById("note").innerHTML;
    
    textbox.setAttribute("name","note_edit");
    textbox.setAttribute("value",adjust);   
    
    document.getElementById("note").innerHTML=textbox;

}
```

I'm new to JavaScript and it's not working. Clicking the link just adds the # to the URL. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementByID`

Consider using a debugger such as Firebug to catch errors like this.

Also, why are you setting the value of the textbox to the note element itself?

Answer (score 0):

You're code contains a typo:

```
var adjust = document.getElementByID("note");
```

should be

```
var adjust = document.getElementById("note");
```

If that doesn't work, start by verifying the function is even called-- add an alert at the top of the function:

```
alert('Edit Note Function Was Called.');
```

EDIT: 
From you're last comment, it sounds like it's doing almost what you want. But taking a look at your script, you're getting an element (called 'note') and assigning it to the variable adjust.  I think what you *want* to do is assign adjust to the **value** of the note element, and not the DOM element iteself, no?

```
var adjust = document.getElementById("note").innerHTML;
```

Since it's a div, you'll want the innerHTML of it.

Edit 2:

```
document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = textbox;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = textbox.value;
```

Comment: Good call. But it's adding a text area without putting the old note in it. It's adding this "<textarea name="note_edit" value="[object HTMLDivElement]" style="margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; height: 47px; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px; width: 220px; "></textarea>"

Comment: added some more to the answer, but true the value of the element, rather than the element itself.

Comment: I edited the code up there, although I'm not sure if it's what you were thinking. It's still not working. What should I do?

Comment: can you describe what's happening when it's ran now?

Comment: Now it's just switching the old note for "[object HTMLTextAreaElement]".

Comment: This is because of the last line in the script. you want the the old note not to be assigned the dom element you created, but again, rather it's value.